# Bone heat weighting: failed to find a solution for one or more bones - no duplicate vertices

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting

When I use the rigify basic human meta rig and try to parent it to the mesh, it displays the problem stated in the title. I've tried deleting duplicate vertices and 12 were deleted but it still didn't work. I've tried applying scale, rotation, location etc. If anyone has any idea how to fix it I would be thankful. Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12PXQhwaMBXeGRlMnn_rT-ZqxL0glM-8Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your mesh is a bit too dense for my computer, so I can't test properly, maybe it explains why it doesn't work, try to scale up the character and armature before parenting, but the best is probably to work with a lighter mesh

Comment: You have some non-manifold geometry in the character's crotch.  I can't figure out how to repair it so I'm not sure if it's the entire cause or not.

Comment: I dissolved the non-manifold geometry and it still fails, so I think your mesh is just too complex for the automatic solver.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it although thanks everyone for your suggestions. I just scaled up everything and then applied scale - I had forgot to do this after scaling everything up before.